# Processing DocBook with MSBuild or XBuild

Tags: msbuild, xbuild, docbook-5

I use to process DocBook and generate PDF/HTML with a Maven plugin (docbkx)... and I'm wondering how to process DocBook with MSBuild or XBuild. Has anyone already tried it? Does it work?

Comment: So far there is no existing MSBuild extension/task for DocBook. You either call DocBook command line utilities directly in your MSBuild script, or develop your own extension and tasks.

Comment: I know there is no plugin... but it should be possible just using a xslt task or whatever... isn't it?